# Why was the DirectX mesh interface removed?

Tags: directx11, directx10

I'm currently working with D3D 11 and if I understood it correctly, D3D 10 had a mesh interface built in to it which was removed in 11.

If this is correct, why was the mesh interface removed? It seems like a useful interface to have.

Comment: Is this causing a problem for you? Are you asking for work-arounds? Things like that are sometimes removed to not limit developers into a specific way of doing things.

Comment: @Byte56 No not really, just takes a bit more time :) Im only asking out of curriosity. I can see how i could limit developers, however 1. if they feelt it limited their potentiall, then they could just make one themself ? 2. I meen there is a limit to how much you can perfect a function to run as fast as possible. I feel this is a good reason to have on standar function for it, to perfect it. Now when you make your own function, sure you can design it to work how you want it to work, but you start att square one everytime, from a performace point of view .

Comment: Frederik, we can only speculate. Maybe this utilitiy stuff was in the way of deeper optimizations, or maybe they just wanted to simplify the interface. Who knows. Voting to close, as in its current form this will only poll speculation and there is no problem to solve here, which is the actual intention of the site. Please check the FAQ for details on what kind of questions are encouraged on the site.

Comment: @MaikSemder with all due respect, if i had know it was only gonna give speculative anwsers it wouldnt have been a question. For all I know it was something major wrong with it and could have sent me down a bad path using the directX 10 interface. Do you think that is something unworthy of knowing for a newbie ?

Comment: @FredrikBostonWestman - I agree that it's probably worth knowing and that there may be useful information in an answer to it, that's not in dispute, and despite that the relevant point is: even given that it may be worth knowing, is it appropriate for this site?

Comment: @mh01 I do, for several reasons. I didnt ask "what is your opinion", I didnt know it was up to speculation. However, the question can still easy be solved without resorting to speculation, with a simple " its up to speculations" which is a valid anwser. There is a diffrence. Then you can discusse if this anwser is relevant to this site. This site is about teaching, and the question teches you something. Because now i atleast know there isn't anything major wrong with it, which is something a newbie like me could be wondering about.

Comment: This is not necessarily speculative anyway; I'm pretty sure the rationale for removing the API (as detailed in my answer) is a matter of public record on of the DX team's blogs. Been looking for a source I can reproduce without violating NDA.

Comment: @mh01 Also, Now that we have established that it is up to speculation, this topic can be closed and all futher question about this can be refered to this, rather then another person come in a year or 2 and goes thrue this process again. But maby that is abit more about how the system of this site is.

Comment: @FredrikBostonWestman - a close as "not constructive" is a valid way of answering as "it's up to speculation", but given Josh's input above I'd like to wait until we see if he can find such a source.

Comment: @mh01 I have already made my case of why this is constructive. Besides, "its up to speculation" is only a way of saying " I don't know" in all cases ( exept for a very few selected questions, like "the meaning of life", and this one hardly falls in to that category). And if you dont know, then you have no reason to be here. Why not just leave it be until somebody that can anwser the question comes around. By close for reasons like this you only demoralize newbies like me to ask good and valid questions.
And Thanks Josh! I really appriate it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

D3D10 core didn't have a mesh class; you're probably thinking of [ID3DX10Mesh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is actually part of the D3DX API. D3DX itself was [wholly deprecated with Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). The relevant math bits were moved [into another library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The higher-level utility interfaces, like mesh, were not ported.

The API was removed because it was a continuation of the evolving focus of D3D and its related APIs: to become narrower in scope, more representative of only the underlying graphics hardware. APIs like the mesh interface were an attempt both to provide something much higher level than the GPU actually does, and to be a one-size-fits-all solution (which is often a lowest-common-denominator solution).

Furthermore, by divorcing the graphics library from the utility library, it's easier for Microsoft to utilize separate (and more appropriate) release vehicles for both, and easier for the components to be updated and versioned independently.

All of the above factors contributed significantly to the decision to deprecate the functionality (which had been underway since the 9-to-10 transition, when the built-in functionality to load meshes from `.x` files vanished).

You should look at the [DirectXTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) or [DirectXTK12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12) for potential replacements to interfaces you miss from D3DX.